# Google Play app link links to the Play homepage instead of the app detail page

Tags: android, google-play, deep-linking

I have a link on my website leading directly to a specific Google Play application:

```
<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=en.my.app" target="_blank">Go to the app</a>
```

The link opens the Google Play app and goes to the app as planned. But on some devices, the user lands on the Google Play homepage instead of the detail app page. The "some devices" run Android 7 and have Google Play app installed.

What might be wrong? Is it some kind of a setting that prevents accessing the app "deep link"?

Answer (score 0):

try this javascript

window.location.href= "market://details?id=en.my.app";

Comment: No, it simply opens Google Play and shows the homepage, instead of the app page. No idea.